# How to Refresh a part of a Page, based on DropDownList selection in MVC?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on ASP.Net MVC. 
I have a ViewPage `SaveStallMenu.cshtml`, which has 2 DropDown Lists
(MF Dropdown, Stalls Dropdown) and a FilerMenu Button

When the page is loaded for the first time, it holds MenuItem of Stall 1.

Now, My question is, when I select an option from `MF Dropdownlist` and `Stall DropdownList`, and click Filter Menu button, the contents in the `<div id="partialViewDiv"></div>` should be refreshed with the Menu Item related to the Stall Selection.

I'm using AJAX for this purpose.

When I click the FilterMenu button

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("uppendStallData", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "", UpdateTargetId = "partialViewDiv" }))
            {
}
```

This Should submit my form to `uppendStallData` ActionMethod, but I don't know why It's not working.

Pardon me, if you find flaws in my explanation of Question. And please try to go through My code and provide your guidance.

I tried many solutions as you can see the Scripts below,but didn't get what I'm trying to do.

**Trial 1:**
If I use above `Ajax.BeginForm`, then `uppendStallData`doesn't get ViewModel data POSTed.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult uppendStallData(AdminVM VM)
{ 

    List<StallsModel> data = _provider.GetStallsList();
    VM.StallNameDDl = data.ToDictionary(x => x.StallId, x => x.StallName);

    List<MFDetailsModel> data1 = _provider.GetMFDetailsList();
    VM.MFNameDDl = data1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.MFName);

    long MFID1 = Convert.ToInt64(VM.StallMenuModel.MFId);

    long STallId = Convert.ToInt64(VM.StallMenuModel.StallId);

    VM.CompleteMenuByStallIDList = _provider.GetCompleteMenuByStallId_List(STallId);   

    return PartialView("_MenuTabs", VM);

}
```

**Trial 2:**
If I call a  as shown below, on FilterMenu button click, 
    this script sends the dropdownlist selected values to `uppendStallData`, but after successful execution of the Method in Contoller, fails to return the PartialView and append to `<div id="partialViewDiv">`.

With Trial2, my script and contoller method is as follow,

```
<script>
    $('#Filter').click(function () {
        var MF_Id = $('#StallMenuModel_MFId').val();
        var Stall_Id = $('#StallMenuModel_StallId').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("uppendStallData", "Admin")',
            data: { MFID: $("#StallMenuModel_MFId").val(), STID: $("#StallMenuModel_StallId").val() },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#partialViewDiv").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
         public PartialViewResult uppendStallData(string MFID,string STID)
         {


             List<StallsModel> data = _provider.GetStallsList();
             VM.StallNameDDl = data.ToDictionary(x => x.StallId, x => x.StallName);

             List<MFDetailsModel> data1 = _provider.GetMFDetailsList();
             VM.MFNameDDl = data1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.MFName);


             long MFID1 = Convert.ToInt64(MFID);

             long STallId = Convert.ToInt64(STID);

             VM.CompleteMenuByStallIDList = _provider.GetCompleteMenuByStallId_List(STallId);    
             return PartialView("_MenuTabs", VM);
         }
```

This is Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SaveStallMenu()
{
    AdminVM VM = new AdminVM();
    List<StallsModel> data = _provider.GetStallsList();
    VM.StallNameDDl = data.ToDictionary(x => x.StallId, x => x.StallName);

    List<MFDetailsModel> data1 = _provider.GetMFDetailsList();
    VM.MFNameDDl = data1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.MFName);
    VM.StallMenuModel = new StallMenuModel();


    VM.CompleteMenuByStallIDList = _provider.GetCompleteMenuByStallId_List(1);                     
    return View(VM);
}


[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult uppendStallData(string MFID,string STID)
{

    List<StallsModel> data = _provider.GetStallsList();
    VM.StallNameDDl = data.ToDictionary(x => x.StallId, x => x.StallName);

    List<MFDetailsModel> data1 = _provider.GetMFDetailsList();
    VM.MFNameDDl = data1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.MFName);


    long MFID1 = Convert.ToInt64(MFID);

    long STallId = Convert.ToInt64(STID);

    VM.CompleteMenuByStallIDList = _provider.GetCompleteMenuByStallId_List(STallId);    
    return PartialView("_MenuTabs", VM);

}
```

Comment: That is way too much code. Please only post the least amount of code that is related to the issue.

Comment: Pardon me for posting too much code. I thought if would be of help to understand my question. Please go through the Scripts ,My Contoller code, MY Trials.

Comment: Which specific part is not working ? When you submit the button, what happens now ? Is it making an ajax call (check browser network tools)? What is inside your form ?

Comment: @Shyju , when please check Trial1 and Trial 2. I have described the problem and what I did.

Comment: Hi Every One.....My page got refreshed . I used this Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for Your Immediate response. This is the answer for My Question.

**SaveStallMenu.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="form-group form-group-select2">
            <label style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">Select MF Name</label>
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StallMenuModel.MFId, new SelectList(Model.MFNameDDl, "Key", "Value", "--- Select ---"), new { @onchange = "FillService()", @class = "form-control" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StallMenuModel.MFId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group form-group-select2">
         <label style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">Select Stall Name</label>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StallMenuModel.StallId, new SelectList(Model.StallNameDDl, "Key", "Value", "--- Select ---"), new { @class = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StallMenuModel.StallId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4" style="float:right;">
    <div class="form-group form-group-select2">
           <input type="submit" value="Filter Menu" id="Filter" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:25px;float:right;" />
     </div>
</div>

    <div id="partialViewDiv"></div>

    <script>
        $('#Filter').click(function () {
            var MF_Id = $('#StallMenuModel_MFId').val();
            var Stall_Id = $('#StallMenuModel_StallId').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("uppendStallData1", "Admin")',
                data: { MFID: $("#StallMenuModel_MFId").val(), STID: $("#StallMenuModel_StallId").val() },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partialViewDiv").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult uppendStallData1(string MFID, string STID)
{
    AdminVM VM= new AdminVM();

    long MFID1 = Convert.ToInt64(MFID);
    long STallId = Convert.ToInt64(STID);

    List<StallsModel> data = _provider.GetStallsList();
    VM.StallNameDDl = data.ToDictionary(x => x.StallId, x => x.StallName);

    List<MFDetailsModel> data1 = _provider.GetMFDetailsList();
    VM.MFNameDDl = data1.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.MFName);             

    VM.CompleteMenuByStallIDList = _provider.GetCompleteMenuByStallId_List(STallId);
    return PartialView("_MenuTabs", VM);
}
```

Comment: THANKS a Lot to all whose POSTS i have refered in stackoverflow, to get this result :)